# How do I know where my program hung or loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have quite a complex WinForm program (C# VS2010 Express, Win7) that I develop and run to debug.
My program holds for a few minutes without any error message.
After some time it will catch one of my error messages, but I can not locate the actual line that will cause it to do whatever it does at the background.
(I used break-points and entered some messages, but for no avail)

It may be reading one of my Excel files, using the ExcelDataReader.
Is there a way to find out what the program is doing while I sit there waiting...
samtal

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but have you run this in debug mode? If so, does it just hang without throwing any form of exception?

Comment: If you have no idea where the problem is you can try adding Debug.WriteLine statements at various points and use those to narrow down the area of difficulty.  These statements output to the "Output" window (debug->windows->output).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried some of the a/m ideas for no avail.
The problem is now solved (error in Excel file parsing), but the answer to the question is still of use for future occasions,
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it in VS2013 Express, and tried using IntelliTrace? It was nicknamed "the historical debugger", and pretty much lets you go back in time.

Comment: You could consider running w/ the debugger attached and then pausing execution. With the debugger you'd then be able to see threads & their call stacks.

Comment: To extend upon what @Warty said, if you try to pause it, but it doesn't stop execution, the process may be hung.